# Failed Qiskit installation with Anaconda on Windows

Tags: python, numpy, pip, anaconda, qiskit

I'm attempting to install Qiskit via pip and Anaconda on my machine. Here's my process

1.) Install Anaconda
2.) Open Anaconda 3 prompt
3.) Create a virtual environment using `conda create -n <environment-name> python=3` command (I've created the environment on different occasions using -n and -m, it creates the environment just fine either way)
4.) Activate the environment
5.) Install Qiskit using `pip install qiskit`

When I run `pip install qiskit`, this mess populates the Anaconda prompt

```
(.venv) C:\Users\brenm>pip install qiskit
```

...

```
 Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\brenm\anaconda3\envs\.venv\python.exe' 'C:\Users\brenm\anaconda3\envs\.venv\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\brenm\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-2psge951\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'Cython>=0.28.5' 'numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"' and platform_python_implementation == '"'"'CPython'"'"'' 'numpy==1.14.0; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"' and platform_python_implementation != '"'"'CPython'"'"'' 'numpy==1.14.5; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'scipy>=0.19.1'
       cwd: None
  Complete output (641 lines):
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6" and platform_system != "AIX" and platform_python_implementation == "CPython"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6" and platform_system != "AIX" and platform_python_implementation != "CPython"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.7" and platform_system != "AIX"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.7" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version >= "3.8" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment
  Collecting Cython>=0.28.5
    Using cached Cython-0.29.21-py2.py3-none-any.whl (974 kB)
  Collecting numpy==1.17.3
    Using cached numpy-1.17.3.zip (6.4 MB)
  Collecting scipy>=0.19.1
    Using cached scipy-1.5.4-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (31.4 MB)
  Collecting setuptools
    Using cached setuptools-51.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (785 kB)
  Collecting wheel
    Using cached wheel-0.36.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
  Building wheels for collected packages: numpy
    Building wheel for numpy (setup.py): started
    Building wheel for numpy (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\brenm\anaconda3\envs\.venv\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\brenm\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8_a1i30j\\numpy_78428c83c4dd4130b43d0502153b50e8\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\brenm\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8_a1i30j\\numpy_78428c83c4dd4130b43d0502153b50e8\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\brenm\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-8jv9o836'
         cwd: C:\Users\brenm\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8_a1i30j\numpy_78428c83c4dd4130b43d0502153b50e8\
    Complete output (292 lines):
    Running from numpy source directory.
    blas_opt_info:
    blas_mkl_info:
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\Users\\brenm\\anaconda3\\envs\\.venv\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\brenm\\anaconda3\\envs\\.venv\\libs', 'C:\\Users\\brenm\\anaconda3\\Library\\lib']
      NOT AVAILABLE
```

...
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy
Running setup.py clean for numpy
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'C:\Users\brenm\anaconda3\envs.venv\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\brenm\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8_a1i30j\numpy_78428c83c4dd4130b43d0502153b50e8\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\brenm\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8_a1i30j\numpy_78428c83c4dd4130b43d0502153b50e8\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' clean --all
cwd: C:\Users\brenm\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8_a1i30j\numpy_78428c83c4dd4130b43d0502153b50e8
Complete output (10 lines):
Running from numpy source directory.

```
    `setup.py clean` is not supported, use one of the following instead:

      - `git clean -xdf` (cleans all files)
      - `git clean -Xdf` (cleans all versioned files, doesn't touch
                          files that aren't checked into the git repo)

    Add `--force` to your command to use it anyway if you must (unsupported).

    ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Failed cleaning build dir for numpy
  Failed to build numpy
  Installing collected packages: numpy, wheel, setuptools, scipy, Cython
      Running setup.py install for numpy: started
      Running setup.py install for numpy: finished with status 'error'
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: 'C:\Users\brenm\anaconda3\envs\.venv\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\brenm\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8_a1i30j\\numpy_78428c83c4dd4130b43d0502153b50e8\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\brenm\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8_a1i30j\\numpy_78428c83c4dd4130b43d0502153b50e8\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\brenm\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-yymyimu0\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --prefix 'C:\Users\brenm\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-2psge951\overlay' --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\brenm\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-2psge951\overlay\Include\numpy'
           cwd: C:\Users\brenm\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8_a1i30j\numpy_78428c83c4dd4130b43d0502153b50e8\
      Complete output (297 lines):
      Running from numpy source directory.

      Note: if you need reliable uninstall behavior, then install
      with pip instead of using `setup.py install`:

        - `pip install .`       (from a git repo or downloaded source
                                 release)
        - `pip install numpy`   (last NumPy release on PyPi)


      blas_opt_info:
      blas_mkl_info:
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\Users\\brenm\\anaconda3\\envs\\.venv\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\brenm\\anaconda3\\envs\\.venv\\libs', 'C:\\Users\\brenm\\anaconda3\\Library\\lib']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      blis_info:
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries blis not found in ['C:\\Users\\brenm\\anaconda3\\envs\\.venv\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\brenm\\anaconda3\\envs\\.venv\\libs', 'C:\\Users\\brenm\\anaconda3\\Library\\lib']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      openblas_info:
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\Users\\brenm\\anaconda3\\envs\\.venv\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\brenm\\anaconda3\\envs\\.venv\\libs', 'C:\\Users\\brenm\\anaconda3\\Library\\lib']
      get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95', 'intelvem', 'intelem', 'flang']'
      customize GnuFCompiler
      Could not locate executable g77
      Could not locate executable f77
      customize IntelVisualFCompiler
      Could not locate executable ifort
      Could not locate executable ifl
      customize AbsoftFCompiler
      Could not locate executable f90
      customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
      Could not locate executable DF
      customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
      Could not locate executable efl
      customize Gnu95FCompiler
      Could not locate executable gfortran
      Could not locate executable f95
      customize G95FCompiler
      Could not locate executable g95
      customize IntelEM64VisualFCompiler
      customize IntelEM64TFCompiler
      Could not locate executable efort
      Could not locate executable efc
      customize PGroupFlangCompiler
      Could not locate executable flang
      don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
        NOT AVAILABLE

      atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
      Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries tatlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\brenm\\anaconda3\\envs\\.venv\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\brenm\\anaconda3\\envs\\.venv\\libs', 'C:\\Users\\brenm\\anaconda3\\Library\\lib']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      atlas_3_10_blas_info:
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries satlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\brenm\\anaconda3\\envs\\.venv\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\brenm\\anaconda3\\envs\\.venv\\libs', 'C:\\Users\\brenm\\anaconda3\\Library\\lib']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      atlas_blas_threads_info:
      Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\brenm\\anaconda3\\envs\\.venv\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\brenm\\anaconda3\\envs\\.venv\\libs', 'C:\\Users\\brenm\\anaconda3\\Library\\lib']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      atlas_blas_info:
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\brenm\\anaconda3\\envs\\.venv\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\brenm\\anaconda3\\envs\\.venv\\libs', 'C:\\Users\\brenm\\anaconda3\\Library\\lib']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      accelerate_info:
        NOT AVAILABLE

      C:\Users\brenm\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8_a1i30j\numpy_78428c83c4dd4130b43d0502153b50e8\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:690: UserWarning:
          Optimized (vendor) Blas libraries are not found.
          Falls back to netlib Blas library which has worse performance.
          A better performance should be easily gained by switching
          Blas library.
        self.calc_info()
      blas_info:
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries blas not found in ['C:\\Users\\brenm\\anaconda3\\envs\\.venv\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\brenm\\anaconda3\\envs\\.venv\\libs', 'C:\\Users\\brenm\\anaconda3\\Library\\lib']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      C:\Users\brenm\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8_a1i30j\numpy_78428c83c4dd4130b43d0502153b50e8\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:690: UserWarning:
          Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
          Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
          numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
          the BLAS environment variable.
        self.calc_info()
      blas_src_info:
        NOT AVAILABLE

      C:\Users\brenm\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8_a1i30j\numpy_78428c83c4dd4130b43d0502153b50e8\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:690: UserWarning:
          Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
          Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
          numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
          the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
        self.calc_info()
        NOT AVAILABLE

      'svnversion' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
      operable program or batch file.
      non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
      lapack_opt_info:
      lapack_mkl_info:
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\Users\\brenm\\anaconda3\\envs\\.venv\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\brenm\\anaconda3\\envs\\.venv\\libs', 'C:\\Users\\brenm\\anaconda3\\Library\\lib']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      openblas_lapack_info:
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\Users\\brenm\\anaconda3\\envs\\.venv\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\brenm\\anaconda3\\envs\\.venv\\libs', 'C:\\Users\\brenm\\anaconda3\\Library\\lib']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      openblas_clapack_info:
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['C:\\Users\\brenm\\anaconda3\\envs\\.venv\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\brenm\\anaconda3\\envs\\.venv\\libs', 'C:\\Users\\brenm\\anaconda3\\Library\\lib']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      flame_info:
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries flame not found in ['C:\\Users\\brenm\\anaconda3\\envs\\.venv\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\brenm\\anaconda3\\envs\\.venv\\libs', 'C:\\Users\\brenm\\anaconda3\\Library\\lib']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      atlas_3_10_threads_info:
      Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\brenm\anaconda3\envs\.venv\lib
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\Users\brenm\anaconda3\envs\.venv\lib
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\brenm\anaconda3\envs\.venv\libs
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\Users\brenm\anaconda3\envs\.venv\libs
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\brenm\anaconda3\Library\lib
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\Users\brenm\anaconda3\Library\lib
      <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
        NOT AVAILABLE

      atlas_3_10_info:
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\brenm\anaconda3\envs\.venv\lib
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\Users\brenm\anaconda3\envs\.venv\lib
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\brenm\anaconda3\envs\.venv\libs
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\Users\brenm\anaconda3\envs\.venv\libs
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\brenm\anaconda3\Library\lib
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\Users\brenm\anaconda3\Library\lib
      <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
        NOT AVAILABLE

      atlas_threads_info:
      Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\brenm\anaconda3\envs\.venv\lib
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\brenm\anaconda3\envs\.venv\lib
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\brenm\anaconda3\envs\.venv\libs
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\brenm\anaconda3\envs\.venv\libs
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\brenm\anaconda3\Library\lib
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\brenm\anaconda3\Library\lib
      <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
        NOT AVAILABLE

      atlas_info:
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\brenm\anaconda3\envs\.venv\lib
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\brenm\anaconda3\envs\.venv\lib
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\brenm\anaconda3\envs\.venv\libs
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\brenm\anaconda3\envs\.venv\libs
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\brenm\anaconda3\Library\lib
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\brenm\anaconda3\Library\lib
      <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
        NOT AVAILABLE

      lapack_info:
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries lapack not found in ['C:\\Users\\brenm\\anaconda3\\envs\\.venv\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\brenm\\anaconda3\\envs\\.venv\\libs', 'C:\\Users\\brenm\\anaconda3\\Library\\lib']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      C:\Users\brenm\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8_a1i30j\numpy_78428c83c4dd4130b43d0502153b50e8\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1712: UserWarning:
          Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
          Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
          numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
          the LAPACK environment variable.
        if getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(lapack))():
      lapack_src_info:
        NOT AVAILABLE

      C:\Users\brenm\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8_a1i30j\numpy_78428c83c4dd4130b43d0502153b50e8\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1712: UserWarning:
          Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
          Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
          numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
          the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
        if getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(lapack))():
        NOT AVAILABLE

      C:\Users\brenm\anaconda3\envs\.venv\lib\distutils\dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
        warnings.warn(msg)
      running install
      running build
      running config_cc
      unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
      running config_fc
      unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
      running build_src
      build_src
      building py_modules sources
      building library "npymath" sources
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\brenm\anaconda3\envs\.venv\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\brenm\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8_a1i30j\\numpy_78428c83c4dd4130b43d0502153b50e8\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\brenm\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8_a1i30j\\numpy_78428c83c4dd4130b43d0502153b50e8\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\brenm\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-yymyimu0\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --prefix 'C:\Users\brenm\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-2psge951\overlay' --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\brenm\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-2psge951\overlay\Include\numpy' Check the logs for full command output.
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\brenm\anaconda3\envs\.venv\python.exe' 'C:\Users\brenm\anaconda3\envs\.venv\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\brenm\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-2psge951\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'Cython>=0.28.5' 'numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"' and platform_python_implementation == '"'"'CPython'"'"'' 'numpy==1.14.0; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"' and platform_python_implementation != '"'"'CPython'"'"'' 'numpy==1.14.5; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'scipy>=0.19.1' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that you're running on Python 3.9. The currently released versions of Qiskit did not have support for Python 3.9 and therefore didn't include precompiled binaries for 3.9 environments. So what is happening is that pip is trying to build Qiskit from source, as a fallback because compatible binaries were not found, which is failing because you're missing build dependencies. The next Qiskit release will include Python 3.9 support and publish binaries for Python 3.9 too. That being said you can fix this in the short term by changing `conda create -n <environment-name> python=3` to a more specific python version like: `conda create -n <environment-name> python=3.8` to use a version of Python that the current release has compatible binaries for.